# ASP NET MVC on IIS 7.5 Serving SVGs with Proper Type

Tags: c#, razor, svg, asp.net-mvc-4

This is closely related to other questions, but my specific question is why these two scenarios produce different behaviors.

1. `FilePathResult` with MIME type argument...

   ```
   public FilePathResult PlainLogoSvg()
   {
           return File(Server.MapPath("~/Art/LogoPlain.svg"), "image/svg+xml");
   }
   ```

   and this in the view

   ```
   <object class="centeredLogo" >
   <embed class="centeredLogo" src="@Url.Action("PlainLogoSvg")"/>
   </object>
   ```

   produce an embedded image on Chrome and FF.
2. Object or embed element (any combo/permutation) with src and type (this MIME type is configured -- by default -- on IIS 7.5)...

   ```
   <object class="centeredLogo" src="@Server.MapPath("~/Art/LogoPlain.svg")" type="image/svg+xml" >
   <embed class="centeredLogo" src="@Server.MapPath("~/Art/LogoPlain.svg")" type="image/svg+xml"/>
   </object>
   ```

   break both Chrome and FF (FF cries for a plugin). Using `Url.Content` fixes it for Firefox.